# Compare current time with the time entered in ngb-timepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using ngb-timepicker in my angular application. I want to compare the user entered time with the current time so that I can add some validations.  The current time I can get using the new Date() object and use currentDate.getTime() but how to I compare this to the time entered in ngb-timepicker.

The time output I get in ngb-timepicker is {hour: 16, minute: 3, second: 0}. Is there a way to convert this to the new Date() object or how can the 2 timing be compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  isEqual() {
    let output = {hour: 16, minute: 3, second: 0};
    let outputDate = new Date();

    outputDate.setHours(output.hour);
    outputDate.setMinutes(output.minute);
    outputDate.setSeconds(output.second);

    if (outputDate.getTime() === new Date().getTime()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following script might help you. Although I prefer vanila js, whenever it comes to dates, I prefer date libraries like momentjs or dayjs.

```js
var t= {hour: 16, minute: 3, second: 0};

var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();

date2.setHours(t.hour);
date2.setMinutes(t.minute);
date2.setSeconds(t.second);
var diffInHours = (date1-date2)/360000;
console.log('diffInHours ',diffInHours );
```